# GPS with J2ME polish

Tags: j2mepolish

I'm developing an GPS based application with J2ME and J2ME polish(2.1.2), i'm facing problems for accessing the location class. I'm getting the following exception

```
Exception in thread "event-thread" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: aa.a(I)V
Nokia/N95:         at aa.a(Native Method)
Nokia/N95:         at ae.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
Nokia/N95:         at b.j(Unknown Source)
Nokia/N95:         at com.allstate.mini.MINIMidlet.commandAction(Unknown Source)
Nokia/N95:         at ax.b(Unknown Source)
Nokia/N95:         at u.b(Unknown Source)
Nokia/N95:         at al.d(Unknown Source)
Nokia/N95:         at bd.keyReleased(Unknown Source)
Nokia/N95:         at javax.microedition.lcdui.Display$KeyEvent.run(Display.java:158)
Nokia/N95:         at org.microemu.device.ui.EventDispatcher.post(EventDispatcher.java:144)
Nokia/N95:         at org.microemu.device.ui.EventDispatcher.run(EventDispatcher.java:74)
Nokia/N95:         at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Please help...

Comment: turn off obfuscation when debugging :-)

Answer (score 0):

Turning off the obfuscation is a good idea when debugging. Do you have obfuscation logs? Even if you don't, you still can guess real stack trace and provide code snippet that actually fails. It seems that some class initialization fails and it is interesting to see the code that class.

Anyway it seems that your exception stack trace is very bad. Native method with obfuscated name looks terribly wrong. If you obfuscate a native method you should obfuscate it in the same way in native implementation. Anyway doing so seems to be very bad idea.

Do you have "native" methods in your code at all? I would expect that there is something wrong with obfuscation settings. Maybe you are trying to obfuscate some library (with native methods) that you use and you shouldn't.

Comment: Instead of turning it off, why not just use the -keep option in Proguard. If it builds without obfuscation it's unlikely to be small enough to deploy on to the device.